# Проблема с переподключением к БД MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, mysqlconnector

```
# CONNECTIONMYSQL
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="remotemysql.com",
    user="USERNAME",
    passwd="PASSWORD",
    database="DATABASE"
)


def db_add_country(Country):
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    mycursor.execute("UPDATE `country` SET `country` = %s WHERE `country`.`id` = 1", (Country,))
    mydb.commit()
    mycursor.close()


def db_read_country():
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `country`")
    row = mycursor.fetchone()
    mycursor.close()
    return row[1]


def poses():
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `poses`")
    pose = mycursor.fetchone()
    mycursor.close()
    bot.send_message(370921204, 'qqqqq')
    pose_delete(pose[1])


def pose_delete(poser):
    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    mycursor.execute("DELETE FROM poses WHERE photo = %s", (poser,))
    mydb.commit()
    mycursor.close()
```

Проблема заключается в том, что при вызове db_add_country и db_read_country все отлично, но если после них вызвать poses, пишет такую ошибку
[image]

poses рабочее, если перед ним не использовать любую из ф-ций выше, то все хорошо

Comment: Я так понимаю, нужно закрывать коннект к БД в функциях, попробую завтра

Comment: Не сработало верхнее утверждение

Comment: Что-то я посмотрел примеры, там нигде не закрывают курсор. Может в этом проблема? Попробуйте не закрывать курсор.

Comment: Проблема сохранилась

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Не нужно закрывать курсоры - это решает проблему